# Windows 7 Jumplists - How to turn off for Windows Explorer ONLY in taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, jumplist

I really like Windows 7's feature of jumplists. It's great at caching recently viewed/visited documents and sites for all kinds of applications. Bravo to the [Windows 7 team](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/) for making this feature easy to use!

How can a user turn off [Windows 7's jumplist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_7#Taskbar) history for each application? This this case, I am looking at Windows Explorer on the Taskbar and its the recent activity on folders.

[image]

**Question**: Is there a way to prevent Windows 7 from caching the history of an application (like Windows Explorer) via the Taskbar without turning off the entire jumplist featureset?

Comment: If you want to disable jump lists for explorer only (and keep jump lists for other applications), try my instructions from related post: http://superuser.com/questions/51454/disable-recent-items-in-jump-lists-for-certain-programs/882741#882741

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/clear-jump-lists-mru-windows-7/) suggests that you:

> Clearing the recent documents history clears the Jump Lists MRU as well. Use these steps:
>
> - Right-click on the Taskbar (Superbar) and choose Properties
> - In the Start Menu tab, uncheck the following option:
>
>   [image]
> - Click Apply
>
> This clears the recent documents history and the Jump Lists MRU. The Pinned items are not cleared.

I tried it out and it works for Explorer, but off course this will also go for all the other jump lists. Until I find a hack that does it, you will either have to disable everything or live with your relatives seeing where you've been ;-)

Off course, you could disable the function and use someting like 7stack or JumpLauncher to create the jump list you want. Also making sure it only shows what you want!

Or keep an eye out for the [Windows 7 blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/06/22/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-jump-into-jump-lists-part-1.aspx) where they go into the details of the API. It shouldn't be long before you can hack the registry to get what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at my answer here...

[Disable Recent Items in Jump Lists for Certain Programs](https://superuser.com/questions/51454/disable-recent-items-in-jump-lists-for-certain-programs/76227#76227)

Comment: Please note that this currently the only working answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent Windows from storing the history as far as I can recall. There is also no way to selective enable or disable the Jump List as per the currently supported API.

You can manage the number of items to display in the Jump List under the Taskbar and Start Menu control panel item, however this will be globally.

Because Explorer is so integrated into Windows, I would imagine any registry edits or hacks to achieve this would cause some problems going forward.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround though.

You can go to the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and create an REG_SZ value named `CleanJumplists` and set its value to `cmd.exe /c del /f /q /s "%Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*"`.

It will clean jump lists at every startup.